# How to begin with carbide.c++ programming

Tags: symbian, carbide

hello as I searched lot but didn't found anything how to start programming with carbide.c++ if is there is any book which can help me out please refer ts link as I am very new to Symbian os programming. So sorry if i HAVE ASKED ANY Thing wrong
Plz help me

Comment: Are you sure you want to learn that? From what I heard Symbian is being killed off.

Comment: Nokia wants you to use Qt. http://qt.nokia.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Carbide.c%2B%2B_Tutorial_1_-_Helloworld) can help you

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_do_I_start_programming_for_Symbian_OS%3F)  can get you started on Symbian and Carbide. Apart from getting used to carbide, you might also want to spend some time learning Symbian specific constructs like Active Objects, Symbian Leave and Cleanup exception handling.
Following links may be useful for this

http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Thread_vs_Active_Object

http://www.symbiantutorial.org/symbian-tutorial/?3._Symbian_Fundamentals